# Which could be the cause of a variable not being printing in an HTML template called from another PHP class?

Tags: php, templates, model-view-controller

I'm developing the base of an MVC project in PHP. I'm advancing with the View part, but something is now working as expected in the rendering of the HTML template.

Here are some contents of the files I'm coding to make this work:

#### my_project_root/views/templates/humans_list.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Humans List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Humans List</h1>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($humans as $human) { ?>
                <li><?php echo $human ?></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### my_project_root/views/HumanView.php

```
<?php

/**
 * A class representing a View
 */
class HumanView
{
    /** @var array contains a list of names */
    var $humans;

    /**
     * Renders the view in HTML
     * @return void
     */
    public function render()
    {
        // Proccess some names to follow some constraints
        $this->process($this->humans);

        // Here I want to use the template in my view, but
        // I need access to the "$humans" variable
        require 'templates/humans_list.php';
    }

    /**
     * Proccess humans names to cut surnames for too long names
     * @param  array &$names
     * @return void
     */
    private function process(&$names)
    {
        foreach ($names as $key => $name)
        {
            if (strlen($name) > 15)
            {
                $name_parts = explode(' ', $name);
                if (isset($name_parts[1])) {
                    $name_parts[1] = strtoupper(substr($name_parts[1], 0, 1)) . '.';
                    $names[$key] = implode(' ', $name_parts);
                }
                else {
                    $names[$key] = substr($name, 0, 15);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // the rest of code
    // ...
}

// In my controller I'll use the view and set the names
// retrieved from my model, but to make testing easier I just
// set the object here and set a mock array to test the
// render method, but It doesn't recognize my $humans variable
$view = new HumanView();
$view->humans = [
    'John First Smith',
    'Peter Second Johnson',
    'Marcus Third Willians',
    'Lucas Fourth Brown'
];
$view->render();
```

I expected that the render method printed the HTML from the template with the name in the $human variable as an unordered list (in the ul tag). But as I said before, the variable is not recognized, tough I already set it.

An html more or less like this:

**Humans List**

- John F. Smith
- Peter S. Johnson
- Marcus T. Willians
- Lucas F. Brown

But I just get this:

**Human List**

Not a single name being printed.

What could be the problem in the code that doesn't let my template to render the variable I just set?

Comment: [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) stated `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /xxx.php on line 10` - see the answer given below, it's your solution.

Comment: I didn't have the error reporting configured to show me warnings in the php output, I really missed that important notice. Thanks for the comment, I just enabled to print E_WARNING type errors to solve more easiy this kind of problems.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to see it all worked out, *cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your template file should also reference the object, since as far as I can see the `$humans` variable won't automagically jump from the class variable into your method like that. Try this:

```
<?php foreach($this->humans as $human) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $human ?></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It prints the list correctly. Thanks for the quick answer!

+1 for the automagically word XD